# SVG: How to align two text elements horizontally by their bottom line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I have a webapp that creates charts using d3. At the bottom of the chart i want to append two text elements: one with fixed content at the bottom right which consists out of one line and one with dynamic content at the bottom left which can have one or multiple lines. The svg code looks basically like this:

```
<text id="dynamicContent" >
<tspan>line1</tspan>
<tspan>line2</tspan>
</text>
<text id="static content">line1</text>
```

The two elements are currently appended to the svg element like this:

```
chart.append("text")
    .attr("id", "dynamicContent")
    .attr("x", valueX1)
    .attr("width", WIDTH - MARGINS.right)
    .text(getDynamicContent())
    .call(wrap, width)
    .attr("y", function () {
        return HEIGHT - $('#dynamicContent')[0].getBBox().height
    });

chart.append("text")
    .attr("class", "source")
    .attr("x", valueX2)
    .attr("y", valueY2)
    .text("staticContent")
    .style("text-anchor", "end");

function wrap(text, width) {
      text.each(function() {
        var text = d3.select(this),
            words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
            word,
            line = [],
            lineNumber = 0,
            lineHeight = 1, // ems
            y = text.attr("y"),
            tspan = text.text(null)
                        .append("tspan")
                        .attr("x", 5)
                        .attr("y", y)
                        .style("dominant-baseline", "hanging");
        while (word = words.pop()) {
          line.push(word);
          tspan.text(line.join(" "));
          if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
            line.pop();
            tspan.text(line.join(" "));
            line = [word];
            tspan = text.append("tspan")
                        .attr("x", 5)
                        .attr("y", y)
                        .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + "em")
                        .text(word);
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

I've been trying for hours to align these two by their bottom lines, but no success. I guess the problem is that the anchor point of the text elements is at the upper left edge. So if i want them always on the bottom of the graphic i have tried things like:

`.attr("y", height - $('#dynamicContent'[0].getBBox().height)`

unfortunately this only seem to work in firefox but in chrome, which just seem to overlay the two lines.

This is such a little detail and i'm getting nowhere, so if anyone has some suggestions i'd be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use dominant-baseline hanging if you want to align by the bottom edge.

Comment: Try `.style("dominant-baseline", "text-before-edge")`